# Push notifications not in Settings > App - Stopped working suddenly (Cert issue?)

Tags: ios, xcode

I've recently switched computers. I thought that I could just login to xcode and have it download the certs I needed and get on with life. However, it didn't so I manually downloaded them and installed them. Most of them showed up but then the prov. profile couldn't be found (even though it was in the keychain).

So like an idiot I clicked on "Fix Issue" in Xcode expecting it to resolve it. However, it revoked my IOS Development Certificate (Team name Foo).

Finally with a bit more fiddling in 'build settings' I was able to get it to push a new build to Test Flight.

Then a user emailed saying push notifications stopped working. The messages go out and the APN doesn't error out any message. Reading more SO posts I discovered going to `Settings > MyApp` and there is no button for notifications anymore (this is the one on the app store already).

My push cert is not expired. Here's a screen of my provisioning profiles, as you can see team dev is invalid:

[image]

And also the valid team prov. profile (dev) does not have any push services while the others do

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how to get pushes working again?

Comment: You can't add push (and I presume other services) to wildcard App IDs

Comment: Are you signing with the right provisioning profile? If you've got a wildcard one, Xcode has a tendency to pick that

Comment: @chedabob It's possible I used the wildcard one when uploading the new beta. However, the older build (in app store) I know was not. Also interesting... I got ahold of another users phone and they can receive pushes ok. They have a Notification button under `Settings > MyApp` too. Perhaps only mine was affected from the beta?

Comment: It's possible. Sometimes the device can get into a weird state with constant reinstalling of the app. What you could try is uninstall, reboot, put the device date forward two days, reboot again, then reinstall the app. What that'll do is allow the app to reregister for push (it can only be done once every 24 hours). If it worked, you should get the OS popup asking to allow notifications.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the suggestion! I tried that with no success so I reset the location/privacy and that forced it to pop open the allow notifications. I accepted but the `Settings > MyApp > Notifications` still isn't showing.